# How to embbed $S^1\times [0, 1]$ in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: general-topology

How to define an embedding of $S^1\times [0, 1]$ in $\mathbb R^2$?

I tried to write $S^1=[0, 1]\sim$ where $0\sim 1$ and I defined $f:S^1\times [0, 1]\longrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ setting, $$f(x, t)=(\cos(\pi x+\pi/2), t),$$ then $f$ is well defined and it is continuous but it's not injective. When I define something injective it is not well defined, so I'm losing the hopes to find it.

Comment: Would you have an idea to get a bijection to $\{ (x,y) : 1 \leqslant x^2+y^2 \leqslant 2\}$?

Comment: What is $S^1\times[0,1]$ geometrically? How could you embed this geometric figure in the plane?

Comment: @DanielFischer I can do that projecting the points of the cylinder $S^1\times [0, 1]$ into the plane in a suitable manner..

Comment: I guess I got the feeling @OlivierBégassat

Comment: Isn't it true that this map is injective though?  I mean, you can put in tons of values $x$ from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\cos(\pi x + \pi/2)$ but they don't "live" in $\mathbb{R}$.  Strictly speaking these elements live in $S^1$ so that you identify periodic points.  Its more proper, perhaps to say $\cos(\pi [x] + \pi /2$ and realize that this mapping operates on equivalence classes (i.e. at this point it is one-one for the same reason $f(0,t)=f(1,t)$ or perhaps more clearly $f([0],t)=f([1],t)$.

Comment: No, the map's not injective. For instance $f(1/3,t)=f(2/3,t)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer the map $f(x, y, t)=(1+t)(x, y)$ does the job, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider, with $x \in \Bbb{S}^1$ and $t \in [0,1]$ 
$$
f(x,t) = \left( (t+1) \cos(2\pi x) ,  (t+1) \cos(2\pi x) \right)
$$
with $ 1 \leq t \leq 2$.

This $f$ is continuous and maps $\Bbb{S}^1 \times [0,1]$ onto a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ shaped like an annulus. $f$ is injective:  It is the projection  of a cylinder 
of unit radiaus and unit height, from a point along the cylinder axis one unit above the cylinder, onto a plane  one unit below the cylinder, and no rays from that point intersect the cylinder more than once.  So $f$ is an example of the desired embedding.

$f$ is not a surjection of $\Bbb{S}^1 \times [0,1]$ onto $\Bbb{R}^2$, and hence is not bijective. You can try to achieve a bijection by composing with a map of $[0,1]$ onto the half-line $p : p>0$.  For example, consider 
$$
g(x,t) = \left( \tan(\pi t/2) \cos(2\pi x) ,  \tan(\pi t/2) \cos(2\pi x) \right)
$$
But that is no longer injective, as the point $0,0$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$ is mapped to by the entire circle $(x \in [0,2\pi),t=0$ in the space $\Bbb{S}^1 \times [0,1]$.  In fact, I think there cannot be such an embedding that is a one-to-one, since the cylinder and the plane are not topologically equivalent.